# The utter futility of bivariate analysis

Tags: multivariate-analysis, feature-selection, exploratory-data-analysis, univariate

Consider the following quote from [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/tri.12895):

> Moreover, univariable prefiltering, sometimes also
>   referred to as “bivariable analysis,” does not add stability
>   to the selection process as it is based on stochastic quantities, and can lead to overlooking important adjustment
>   variables needed for control in an etiologic model.
>   Although univariable prefiltering is traceable and easy to
>   do with standard software, one should better completely
>   forget about it as it is neither a prerequisite nor providing
>   any benefits when building multivariable models.

This claim is somewhat disconcerting, as many data scientists include bivariate analysis in their EDA before modeling. Should the practice hence be discontinued?

(It may of course be that this is true only in inferential contexts, such as medical research, and not in predictive ones. If so, what is the reason?)

Comment: This statement is aimed more at an inferential setting, such as studies in the medical literature.  But in predictive contexts, I see no reason why this can't be done.

Comment: Can you define "bivariate analysis" and "bivariable analysis" in the context of your question? If you're talking about using simple (single variable) regression to select variables, see [omitted variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias) and [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_paradox) (though the general case is the reversal paradox, though it needn't result in reversal necessarily).

Comment: "Bivariable analysis" is *not* bivariate analysis generally!  It refers to a specific method of using p-values for variable selection.  See https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8699212.